# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException not able to construct instance of class

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

class A{
    @JsonProperty("B")
    List<B> b;
    @JsonProperty("abc")
    String abc;
}

public abstract class B{
    @JsonProperty("def")
    String def;
}

public class C extends B{
    @JsonProperty("xyz")
    String xyz;
}
```

json:

```
{
  "B": [
    {
      "def": "<text1>"
    },
    {
      "def": "<text1>",
      "xyz": "<text2>"
    }
  ],
  "abc": "<text3>"
}
```

Response has content of above `json`

```java
A a  = response.readEntity(A.class);
```

Error:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException:` Problem with reading the data, class A, ContentType: application/json.
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of B: abstract types either need to be mapped
```

Is there any way we can create an instance of class which contain object of an abstract class?

Comment: Abstract class can't have an instance unless subclassed. By the way, what is `import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;` doing at the end of the code? Looks odd.

Comment: Here class B is abstract and its subclass is C so I think it should be able to create instance of B.    And I imported Response in first line

Answer (score 0):

Because class `B` is an `abstract` `class` you need to provide type which can be used to instantiate `B` type. In your case is class `C`. You can instruct `Jackson` to do that by:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = C.class)
abstract class B {
```

or on field level:

```
@JsonProperty("B")
@JsonDeserialize(contentAs = C.class)
private List<B> b;
```

Comment: ThankU @michał-ziober , but suppose there are multiple implementation of abstract class B(in that case we can not use specific class in annotation) then is there any way we can achieve above scenario?

Comment: @BhawaniSingh, in that case you need to dynamically "guess" a type and create an instance of that type. How do you want to do that? Can you guess by properties in a `JSON` object? I do not see any property which defines type.

Answer (score 0):

This will include class name as JSON property "class".

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public abstract class B {
}

public class C extends B {
  public int x;
}
public class D extends B {
  public String name;
}

public class A {
  public List<B> items;
}
and this could result in serialized JSON like:

{ "items" : [
  { "class":"D", "name":"TXT" },
  { "class":"C", "x":123 }
]}
```

similar logic can be used for above mentioned problem for that we need to `add some additional info` in JSON.